# What are the first threats that come to your mind when you see a basic web server?

Tags: webserver

If somebody writes a web server in a programming language, a server that listens on a socket (e.g. 80) and serves files with headers. What are the first threats it can experience once it goes out in the wild?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would imagine that hackers will start with a buffer overflow attack.  They could do things like call URLs that are too long or request headers that have malformed components.